# docker image couldn't build for amd64 on arm64

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For the past few days, I've been trying to create a Docker image for my .NET project to deploy on a server. However, all my attempts in the last week have been unsuccessful when I tried to build the image for amd64 on Mac M1.

When I used docker:

```
docker build -t rumit0/asdf --platform=linux/amd64 --no-cache
```

While building the image, the process got stuck at the point where the `dotnet restore "Project.Web/Project.Web.csproj"` command was running for a long time. The only thing that was increasing was the memory consumption, which I incidentally increased in the Docker settings, While using `buildx`, the situation remains the same.

```
docker build -t rumit0/asdf .
```

works fine.

Turned on Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation flag.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

COPY *.sln .
COPY ["ProjectX/ProjectX.csproj", "ProjectX/"]

RUN dotnet restore "ProjectX.Web/ProjectX.Web.csproj"

COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /source/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectX.Web.csproj" -c release -o /app --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectX.Web.dll"]
```